# How do I find unused records using an outer join?

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

Given, the following tables:

```
+--------------+
| CLASSES      |
+==============+
| name | room  |
+------+-------+
| 1A   | A1.01 |
| 1B   | NULL  |
| 1C   | A1.03 |
+------+-------+

+-------+
| ROOMS |
+=======+
| id    |
+-------+
| A1.01 |
| A1.02 |
| A1.03 |
+-------+
```

I expect the following result:

```
+--------------+
| UNUSED ROOMS |
+==============+
| id           |
+--------------+
| A1.02        |
+--------------+
```

How would you accomplish this using an Outer Join?

Comment: Try googling your question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query does exactly what was asked for:

```
SELECT rooms.*
FROM rooms
  LEFT JOIN classes ON rooms.id = classes.room
WHERE
  classes.room IS NULL;
```

Trying to explain what is happening here:

After Left Joining `classes` on `rooms`, you get this result:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| LEFT JOINED                                |
+============================================+
| rooms.id    | classes.name | classes.room  |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| A1.01       | 1A           | A1.01         |
| A1.02       | NULL         | NULL          |
| A1.03       | 1C           | A1.03         |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Since Left Join returns *all* records of the left table (which is `rooms`), even if `rooms.id` doesn't match `classes.room` since the latter is null, the `rooms` columns will still be returned. Mind that `classes.name` is also null, since the record was not matched. I know this is a bit confusing for beginners. (Like myself, I just wanted to share my experience. Sorry for sounding a bit confused.)

So as you can see, all that is needed to be done from here is to filter out the `classes` where `room` is null.

```
+--------------+
| UNUSED ROOMS |
+==============+
| id           |
+--------------+
| A1.02        |
+--------------+
```